# Angular 4 - Unhandled Promise rejection: Object(...) is not a function ; Zone:

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, angular6

I don't know suddenly what happened but now I am facing some issue. Till the time app was working fine. But now whenever I am trying to run the app from android studio or xcode, I can see below error on chrome console. I did some research but not able to find anything. It would be great if someone could help me.
I am not using any kind of http service.

**Current configuration of project- 
1. ionic - v3
2. Angular - 4
3. Cordova**

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Object(...) is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at new ApplicationRef (vendor.js:5187)
    at _createClass (vendor.js:8954)
    at _createProviderInstance (vendor.js:8916)
    at initNgModule (vendor.js:8849)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (vendor.js:9575)
    at createNgModuleRef (vendor.js:9564)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (vendor.js:11389)
    at NgModuleFactory_.create (vendor.js:12091)
    at vendor.js:4987
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at new ApplicationRef (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:5187:64)
    at _createClass (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:8954:20)
    at _createProviderInstance (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:8916:26)
    at initNgModule (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:8849:32)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:9575:9)
    at createNgModuleRef (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:9564:12)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:11389:12)
    at NgModuleFactory_.create (file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:12091:25)
    at file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js:4987:43
    at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
```

Comment: In some of function you just handled resolve cases, and havenot handled rejection cases. Try adding rejection function in then.

Comment: I gone through the project again.. Not able to find resolve.. I haven't used resolve case in my project.